# defining a delegate that can return a type with a generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

I have the following classes

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(){}
}

public class MyClass<T> : MyClass
{
    public MyClass(){}
}
```

I would like to define a delegate that can return `Task<MyClass<T>>` or `Task<MyClass>`.

I declared it as follows.

```
public delegate Task<T> MyFunc<out T>() where T : MyClass;
```

but I get an error

```
Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be invariantly valid on 'MyFunc<T>.Invoke()'. 'T' is covariant.
```

If I don't use the `out` modifier and I use the delegate to return a `MyClass<T>` object like follows

```
public Task<MyClass> ff(MyFunc<MyClass> f)
{
    return f();
}

public void aa()
{
    ff(() => Task<int>.Run(() => new MyClass<int>()));
}
```

I get a different error

```
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<MyClass<int>>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<MyClass>'
error CS1662: Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'MyFunc<MyClass>' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type
```

Is there any way to achieve what I want?

Comment: I don't understand your request, but for sure the last error would be corrected using this statement: `ff(() => Task.Run(() => new MyClass()))` instead of `ff(() => Task<int>.Run(() => 5));`

Comment: I fixed the example so it would reflect what I want I changed the line to 

     `ff(() => Task<int>.Run(() => new MyClass<int>()));`

Answer (score 0):

You can have a signature of the delegate without the constraint and a returning value `Task<int>` of the function like this:

```
    public delegate Task<T> MyFunc<T>();

    public Task<int> ff(MyFunc<int> f)
    {
        return f.Invoke();
    }

    public void aa()
    {
        ff(() => Task<int>.Run(() => 5 ));
    }
```

or if you want to use the `MyClass` in the delegate signature you should have the code reflecting this:

```
    public delegate Task<T> MyFunc<T>() where T : MyClass;

    public Task<MyClass<int>> ff(MyFunc<MyClass<int>> f)
    {
        return f.Invoke();
    }

    public void aa()
    {
        ff(() => Task<MyClass<int>>.Run(() => new MyClass<int>()));
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the help but this is not what I want. i would like ff method to return Task<MyClass>. I thought by using the out modifier Iwould be able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am confused about what you actually want, but if you just want the ff method to return `Task<MyClass>` like you stated in your comment to Daniele, then I'm not sure why you wouldn't just write something like this:

```
class Program
{
    public delegate Task<T> MyFunc<T>();

    public Task<MyClass> ff(MyFunc<MyClass> f)
    {
        return f();
    }

    public void aa()
    {
        ff(() => Task.Run(() => new MyClass()));
    }

}



public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass() { }
}
```